# Access class properties in the form of dict python django

Tags: python, class, dictionary, eval, python-internals

I am a newbie to python/Django. Please help me with this problem.
I am trying to instantiate these class properties but i am not able to do it.

**This is my class**

```
class PricingContext(object):
    def __init__(self, order=None, availability=False):
        self.order = order
        self.availability = availability

    @property
    def available_suites(self):
        if self.availability:
            availability = calculate_available_suites(self.order)
            return availability

    @property
    def price_codes(self):
        return self.order.get('price_codes')

    @property
    def purchased_date(self):
        return self.order.order_items[0].get('purchased_date')

    @property
    def suite_type(self):
        return self.order.order_items[0]['item_name']
```

And i am trying to instantiate like this

```
context_obj = PricingContext(context, availability)
eval(self.discount_function, None, context_obj)
```

Assume `self.discount = "'PRICE_CODE' in context_obj.price_codes"`

But here, it throws this error.
​*TypeError: locals must be a mapping*​

If I try to pass **context_obj.__dict__** then it instantiates only 
self.order and self.availability because they are mentioned in **init**

I want that all these properties to be instantiated without initializing in init as it won't go with my usecase.
I want to call each property only when it is required by eval().

Let me know if it is possible or is there a way to do it.
Thanks in advance for help. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea. Why do you need the discount function to be stored as a string?

Comment: @DanielRoseman eval takes up first parameter in the form of string. So, here discount_function is a rule which evaluates on the basis of the dict passed in the third param.

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. Why do you want to use eval at all? It's almost always better to avoid it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What would be the other way to go about it?
Please let me know how to solve it

Comment: I am trying to use it to evaluate the entered expression which will be entered by the user. So i want to give multiple options to the user to define that rule.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `eval` is expecting a mapping. A mapping is the abstract parent class of a `dict` and it has a specific interface. The easiest way to make your own Mapping is to use collections.Mapping, for example that maps lower case letters to upper case letters:

```
import collections
from string import ascii_lowercase

class toUpper(collections.Mapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if len(key) == 1 and key in ascii_lowercase:
            return key.upper()
        else:
            raise KeyError

    def __len__(self):
        return 26

    def __iter__(self):
        return ((k, k.upper()) for k in ascii_lowercase)
```

All you need to do is make your own mapping where the keys are the variable names needed by eval. The value for each key can be computed on the fly or stored in some cache depending on your needs.

Just for fun:

```
 eval('"".join([c, a, p, s, l, o, c, k])', None, toUpper())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sending me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.

I have added this in my class. Now eval looks for the key and access the corresponding property.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__getattribute__(key)
```